# Messages being overwritten - C

Tags: c, function, message-queue

I have the following two functions, SendMessage and ReceiveMessage, where as the name says they send a message to a queue and receive a message from the queue. My problem is that every message that is being received is being over written by the last inputted element. For example - inputted messages would be a b c, outputted messages would be c c c.

```
typedef struct{
    int front, rear;
    char* elements[MAX_MESSAGES];
}queue;


int main(){
    char choice;
    char element[MAX_MSG_LEN];

    queue q;
    create(&q);

    while(1){
        printf("\n1) Send Message");
        printf("\n2) Receive Message");
        printf("\n0) Quit");
        printf("\nEnter choice:");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':              
                    printf("\nEnter message to send:");
                    scanf("%s", element);
                    sendMessage(&q, element);                
                break;
            case '2':
                    receiveMessage(&q);              
                break;              
            case '0':
                printf("\nQuitting");
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Incorrect. Re-enter.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

void create(queue *pq){
    pq -> front = pq->rear = -1;
}

void sendMessage(queue *pq, char element[MAX_MSG_LEN]){
    int i;

    if(pq -> front == -1)
        pq -> front = pq -> rear = 0;

    else if (pq -> rear == MAX_MESSAGES - 1){
        for(i = pq -> front; i <= pq -> rear; i++)
            pq -> elements[i-pq -> front] = pq -> elements[i];

        pq -> rear = pq -> rear + pq -> front -1;
        pq -> front = 0;
    }
    else pq -> rear++;

    pq -> elements[pq->rear] = element;
}

void receiveMessage(queue *pq){
    char* temp;

    temp = pq -> elements[pq -> front];

    if(pq -> front == pq -> rear)
        pq -> front = pq -> rear = -1;
    else
        pq -> front++;

    printf("\nReceived message is %s\n", temp);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `for(i = pq -> front; i <= pq -> rear; i++)
            pq -> elements[i-pq -> front] = pq -> elements[i];`? I don't see why you'd be reassigning elements in the queue. Assuming it's a circular queue, I would expect `sendMessage` would be checking `front` versus `rear` to determine whether the queue is full and, if not, incrementing `rear` and storing the new message there, and in each case, checking for wrap-around of `rear`.

Comment: I would try to avoid the `-1` sentinel value, and use unsigned types as much as possible.

Comment: [`queue` is a template class in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/). I don't think it exists in C, which is what this question is about. Show us the code for your `queue` implementation so we can properly answer the question. Questions should include enough code to reproduce the error and still compile.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of this queue in action. The `queue` class does not exist in the base C language.

Comment: queue is a structure, i edited the question for you to see.. @JoelTrauger

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. Please edit the code so that it is.

Comment: is that better @klutt

Comment: @MrMosby Yes that is better. See my answer below. I think you'll find it useful. Remember *strings do not exist in C*. You cannot assign strings values by throwing pointers around like you can in C++ and other high-level languages that support OOP and the `string` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `strcpy` function instead of just passing pointers around. When you write `pq -> elements[i-pq -> front] = pq -> elements[i];` you are just copying a pointer value. When you call the `scanf` function and give it the address for `element` you are overwriting the array that pointer points to. All the pointers that point to that array will then point to the overwritten array of characters.

To avoid this, use the `strcpy` function to copy the values of the array the pointer points to, to a new array like this:

```c
strcpy(pq -> elements[i-pq -> front], pq -> elements[i]);
            //pq -> elements[i-pq -> front] = pq -> elements[i];
```

Do this for every instance you assign a value from the `elements` array in the `sendMessage` and `receiveMessage` functions.

Also fix your segmentation fault in the code below. What happens when `pq -> front` is `-1`?

```c
void receiveMessage(queue *pq){
    char temp[MAX_MSG_LEN];

    //--> SEG FAULT <--//
    strcpy(temp, pq -> elements[pq -> front]);
    //--> SEG FAULT <--//

    if(pq -> front == pq -> rear)
        pq -> front = pq -> rear = -1;
    else
        pq -> front++;

    printf("\nReceived message is %s\n", temp);
}
```